# Weblogic how to publish metadata file with WLST

Tags: python, oracle, weblogic, wlst

I'm trying to figure out how to do in WebLogic the following using code (using WLST):
[ProductionDomain->Environment->Servers->ProductionServer->Federation Services->SAML 2.0 General->Publish Meta Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USeld.png)

unfortunately on guides it only says that "Operations on the metadata file are available via the com.bea.security.saml2.providers.registry.Partner Java interface." but yet the following interface does not seem to provide any relevant method for publishing the xml metadata file.

any suggestions how to implement the operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in online mode use this wlst command :

```
serverRuntime() 
cmo.getSingleSignOnServicesRuntime().publish('myMetadata.xml', false)
```